# Swig: either missing /bits/c++config.h or includes cannot be found

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am having huge troubles with swig. 
I want to write a library in C++ to include it and use it as python extension.
The problem is, that swig complains about additional includes, that it cannot find, when i use the following command:

```
swig -python -Isrc myModule.i
```

The output is as follows:

```
Error: unable to find 'forward_list'
```

and a few more that are specified in my interface file:

```
/* file: myModule.i */
%module myModule
%{
#include <forward_list>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include "myModule.h"
%}

%include "myModule.h"
%include <forward_list>
%include <string>
%include <set>
```

I followed the intructions to incorporate additional directories and used the following command:

```
swig -python -I/usr/include/c++/5 -Isrc myModule.h
```

Then swig was complaining about missing files in

```
/usr/include/c++/5/bits
```

For example c++config.h. I have both c++-multilib and g++-multilib installed.
However, these packages have been installed to another directory:

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits
```

So I can decide now, if I want swig to find the necessary files by specifying -I to these, or to be able to find the includes, which are located in the other folder.
What can I do or rather, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: `<forward_list>` was added in C++11 check your compiler and compiler flags. see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header

Comment: That question linked is irrelevant here. the asker's not directly including parts of bits. I suspect this stems from not having C++11 enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I have simply forgotton to add the  `-c++` option in the command. This obviously lets swig know, that it is c++ code. The error messages concerning `bits/<xy>.h` are gone then.